# support count or weighted support count?

Tags: product, similarity, apriori, affinity

I have a set of transactions that contain products and I am working on partitionning these products into clusters based on their affinity. In the literature, I found two measures for the product affinity. One is the support count and the other is the weighted support count. Which one should I use and when ?

Answer (score 1):

The R package `arules` has an implementation to calculate affinity as defined by

> Charu C. Aggarwal, Cecilia Procopiuc, and Philip S. Yu (2002)
>        Finding localized associations in market basket data, *IEEE Trans.
>        on Knowledge and Data Engineering,* 14(1):51-62.

Have a look at: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/versions/1.6-1/topics/affinity